# Regex for string between two of a symbol but not three of that symbol

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing through a document and would like to split it up using php's preg_split().

The document is organized into sections with headings of:

```
==Section Title==
```

The problem is that each section has subsections with headings of:

```
===Subsection Title===
```

Question:  Is there a way to use regex to parse through the document for things that are between two equal signs but not between three equal signs?

Thanks!

P.S. I am trying to learn regex, but I still find it pretty confusing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one that should work:

```
(?<!=)==(?!=)(.*)(?<!=)==(?!=)
```

How it works:

The pattern `(?<!=)==(?!=)` appears twice (beginning and end). It matches two equals signs that are not preceded or followed by another equals sign using `(?<!=)` (negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) and `(?!=)` (negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). The purpose of this is to ensure that you don't accidentally match two equals signs that are part of a larger group such as `===`.

The `(.*)` in the middle matches whatever text exists between the two pairs of `==`.

Comment: I think you need `^` and `$` around it. Otherwise, it will simply match the part of the second line from the 2nd character (.* will gobble up the first of the 3 `=` characters on the right).

Comment: Thanks You!!! I had to escape the = in the negative lookaheads, but after that it seems to work.

Comment: @Barmar: Very true, I reworked the regex so that it doesn't have this issue. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you are just worried about those headings, or parsing all of WikiCreole, but libraries are available for parsing WikiCreole in PHP.

http://wiki.wikicreole.org/Libraries

Comment: it's funny how you know what I am trying to do =)

Comment: @BenLee, Sorry, but I cannot.  I have never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there isn't any white space at the start/end of the line:

```
^==[^=]+==$
```

Comment: Be sure and specify multiline mode, too: `'/^==[^=]+==/m'`